# why do we have more than one constructor and destructor in one class?

Tags: c++

Can any one tell why do we have copy and move constructors and assignments are explicitly deleted how it impacts on class behavior

```
class System : public std::enable_shared_from_this<System> {
  public:
    System();
    virtual ~System();
    System(const System&) = delete;
    System(System&&) = delete;
    System& operator=(const System&) = delete;
    System& operator=(System&&) = delete;
     ---
   }
```

Comment: There's only one destructor, the rest are various constructors and two stray assignment operators. Why do you think that's "too many" ?

Comment: I can see only one constructor, the other declarations are deleting the default constructors and assignment operators.

Comment: There is one default constructor, one destructor, then the copy and move constructors are explicitly deleted, and then the copy and move assignments are also deleted. So, in total there is exactly one constructor and one destructor, which isn't very many at all. You should probably get yourself [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Is there any chance that your actual doubt is why the copy and move constructors are explicitly deleted and how does it affect the behaviour of the class?

Comment: yes my intention is why the copy and move constructors are explicitly deleted

Answer (score -1):

What is confusing you, most likely is the inheritance. When you write `class myclass : public baseclass` the compiler auto-generates you a constructor, destructor, copy-constructor, and assignment operators. These are basic functions that, until redefined, have an empty body, only calling the base class's respective functions. This is what you see here, deleting all, but the constructor and destructor.

Also, note that you can overload a function virtually infinite times, including the constructor, so you can have more than one.